# Why do my 7W LED ground lights flicker even though they're on a transformer

Tags: led, exterior

I bought:
Check this out at Amazon.com
LEONLITE 7W In-Ground Landscape Lighting, IP67 Waterproof LED Outdoor Well Light, UL Listed Linkable Pathway Lights, 12-24V, 3000K Warm White, for Yard, Garden, Patio, Pack of 6 [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07MB1N6Q2/ref=cm_sw_r_other_apa_i_PgLLEb8NT16EG](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MB1N6Q2)

Comment: Depending on the type of flickering it could be different causes. If the flickering is almost constant, and close to or half the frecuency of the power line (60Hz, 30Hz), it may be due to the transformer working close to it's maximum capacity (it's called ripple at the rectifier's output, and sometimes a larger condensator can be of help). If the flickering is quite random and unpredictable, it maybe something else (cables, or even some malfunctioning lamp). Note: for six 7W lamps, you'll need 42W rectifier output.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Total wattage according to the labels from the box is 42W (6fixtures @7W), based on the reviews apparently they draw double of what it's spec. That's why I went ahead and bought 96watt transformer.

Comment: Also the flickering it's a mix mix, start out flickering rapidly, then slow down, some actually only flicker every 8 seconds

Comment: Do you have any other external artifact that could interfer with the proper functioning of the lamps, such as dimmer or motion sensor? Have you tested each lamp individually to discard cabling issues?

Comment: You might try turning off all other items in your house via flipping the switches in your panel to see if there is a device on the other circuits. This is a LOT easier than going around the house to turn everything off and no chance of missing something

Comment: Can you link the power supply that is being used with it?

Comment: Where is the switch: primary hot, primary neutral or secondary side of the transformer? Is it a transformer with an electronic circuit or without, i.e. is it a DC power supply or a  pure AC/AC transformer? Do they flicker when the switch is in (supposed) position on or off?